# ML model for text detection similar to object detection?

Tags: object-detection, optical-character-recognition

I'm n00b to ML and am looking for a text detection model which could tell me a box of pixels has X% possibility to be a word ABC, very similar to common object detection models like [these](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md).

I searched around and the closest I found is [this](https://github.com/argman/EAST), which gives the box of the text but it doesn't recognize the word. There're also libraries/models around which could interpret a text bitmap to words, like OCR.

So is there any popular existing model fits my need? Or did I miss anything? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a popular Tesseract OCR engine developed by Google.  As of the time of this writing, the latest stable version is 4.1.0, released on July 7, 2019, which is neural network (LSTM)-based.  The main Github repository is https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract.

There are R and Python bindings for this engine.  If you are using R, for example, you can browse this article covering the `tesseract` package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tesseract/vignettes/intro.html.  It shows how it can provide a user with the coordinates of bounding boxes for each word in an image and a confidence score.

If you are using Python, the `pytesseract` library can accomplish the same task: https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract, https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/.  As described in the first link, the `image_to_data` function returns result containing box boundaries, confidences, and other information.